# What is a nice Emacs Livescript mode?

Tags: emacs, livescript

I switched to [Livescript](http://livescript.net/) for some tasks with success, however I didn't find a basic emacs mode for it. I'd like one with at least good indentation support.

I found:

- [livescript-mode](https://github.com/mk0x9/livescript-mode), the one pointed by the official doc. It only converts the current file or buffer to JS. No indentation support.
- [livescript-mode (by bdowning)](https://github.com/bdowning/livescript-mode), a fork from coffee-mode, but it messes up the indentation at each new line. This one has 158 forks, so hopefully someone came up with a decent set ?
- [livescript-mode (by yhisamatsu)](https://github.com/yhisamatsu/livescript-mode) is the most starred on github. It doesn't handle indentation either. It has a lot of private functions to deal with the syntax table.

How do you write livescript in emacs, what is your current configuration ?

Comment: I admit I just use CoffeeScript most of the time...

Answer (score 1):

After a few weeks of use, actually I had misregarded the second livescript mode (bdowning's). The indentation isn't that clever but not bad, it doesn't go in our way at least, and it has the expected compile-buffer/file/region functions.